# Use openlayers with typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

I'm trying to use new ol (>6.0.0) on my project with typescript. In a previous versions I could just use it like this -

```
///<reference path='../@types/openlayers/index.d.ts'/>
```

And use global ol object e.g

```
ol.source.OSM()
```

But newer versions of ol don't really have this single object, but a number of modules. I try to reference path to folder with typings for new ol, but it doesn't really seem to work. On the other hand, when I try to import them e.g

```
import * as Map from 'ol/Map'
```

It says, that I have to use module:"system" or module:"AMD" in my typescript config. But is it the only way? My project structure is rather comples, and it would be hard to implement requirejs or systemjs. What's the best solution in this case?

UPD:
I've added systemJS at my index.html. But there's a huge problem - whenever I try to import my js file, using systemjs it works quite fine - I can use all functions which are declared inside of it and so on. However, when I include any import into my file (e.g import {A} from "someconst"), systemjs stops working with tons of error messages. And I'm completely confused why is it like that.

Comment: A full build is still available https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: Oh, true. But can I somehow use it with typescript? I mean, there are no typings :(

Answer (score 2):

The way you import has changed - do not use the `ol` namespace.

Import the types explicitly:

```
import { Map } from 'ol';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import { Coordinate } from 'ol/coordinate';
// etc
```

Regarding typings, the official typings are not quite there yet, but I have found https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol to work well.

Comment: Well, yes, I got this part. But I mean, for doing it this way I need to add requireJS or SystemJS in my project. And I kinda want to find another way if there's one

Comment: I'm not sure you do - check this stackblitz which only has `ol` and `@types/ol` packages: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-ol-imports?file=index.ts .Unless stackblitz is handling it internally?

Comment: Hmm, I guess, I can't do it this way, because my typescript configured to have an outputfile. Because of that it asks me to use module:"System" or module:"AMD" if I try to import/require modules

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have `outFile` set in your tsconfig? If you need a single output file, could you potentially use a bundler to create that after tsc does its work?